# JSch Multiple Channels same Session

Tags: java, session, jsch

I am trying to open multiple channels via single `jSCH session`.
Here is my code.

```
public class PoolTest {

    private static Hashtable<String, Session> pool = new Hashtable<>();
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws JSchException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSchException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        PoolTest test = new PoolTest();
        test.runCommand("show system");
        test.runCommand("show version");
    }

    private void runCommand(String command) throws JSchException, IOException, InterruptedException{
        Session session = createNewSession();
        System.out.println(session.isConnected());
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
        ((ChannelShell) channel).setPtyType("dumb");
        channel.connect();
        OutputStream ops = channel.getOutputStream();
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(ops, true);

        channel.connect();
        ps.println(command); 

        ps.close();

        InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
        byte[] bt=new byte[1024];


        while(true)
        {

            while(in.available()>0)
            {
                int i=in.read(bt, 0, 1024);
                if(i<0)
                    break;
                String str=new String(bt, 0, i);
                //displays the output of the command executed.
                System.out.print(str);


            }
            if(channel.isClosed())
            {

                break;
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            channel.disconnect();
        }
        channel.disconnect();
    }
    private Session createNewSession() throws JSchException{
        if(pool.get("10.94.101.235")==null){
        System.out.println("creating new session");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session;
        session = jsch.getSession("unknown", "10.94.101.235", 22);
        session.setPassword("wont_tell");
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setTimeout(60000);
        session.connect();
        pool.put("10.94.101.235", session);
        return session;
        }
        else 
            return pool.get("10.94.101.235");
    }
}
```

As expected the first command gives proper data. However the second command shows false for the `isConnected` call.

> Exception in thread "main" com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: session is down
>           at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.openChannel(Session.java:844)
>           at com.dell.supportassist.collector.test.PoolTest.runCommand(PoolTest.java:40)
>           at com.dell.supportassist.collector.test.PoolTest.main(PoolTest.java:34)

Any ideas on why session got disconnected?

Comment: I'm wildly speculating that you're connecting to a Cisco, which doesn't support creating multiple shell channels (even though you tried to disconnect the first channel - it's probably lingering because you didn't explicitly close the `InputStream in`).

Comment: It's a Dell switch..Also i tried closing the InputStream explicitly but no luck.

Comment: There is a good chance that it follows the same behaviour as the cisco in that you *must* keep the first channel open for the entire duration of the session. If you close it, then it tears down the entire session. (First comment was wrong, Cisco does support multiple channels per session).

Comment: Why are you disconnecting the channel twice? Why is your method called `createNewSession()` when it can return an old session?